# Delete array in loop if items are different type of variable

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, gettype

Hello i have a problem too difficult to solve...
I have a **multidimensional array** and i want to delete each element that is a different type of variable.
I would like to check that all the elements have the right kind of data.

```
<?php
    $array48mom = Array( 
        Array(1530270934000,19.4034,-155.2675,3,1,'E',612),
        Array('1530270934000',19.4034,-155.2675,3,2,'E',612),
        Array(1530270934000,19.4034,-155.2675,3,3,'E',612)
    );
?>
```

And now the code with function:

```
<?php 
    $array48mom = pulisci_array48mom($array48mom);

    function pulisci_array48mom(&$array48mom){
        for($i = 0; $i < count($array48mom); $i++) {    
            if( (
                (is_int($array48mom[$i][0]) == true) 
                || (is_double($array48mom[$i][1]) == true) 
                || (is_double($array48mom[$i][2])== true) 
                || (is_numeric($array48mom[$i][3]) == true) 
                || (is_numeric($array48mom[$i][4]) == true) 
                || (is_string($array48mom[$i][5]) == true) 
                || (is_int($array48mom[$i][6]) == true)) == false
            ){
                unset($array48mom[$i]); 
            }
        }
        $array48mom = array_values($array48mom);    
        return $array48mom; 
    }
    print_r($array48mom);
?>
```

**OUTPUT** should be this:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
     (
        [0] => 1530270934000
        [1] => 19.4034
        [2] => -155.2675
        [3] => 3
        [4] => 1
        [5] => 'E'
        [6] => 612
     )   

 [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1530270934000
        [1] => 19.4034
        [2] => -155.2675
        [3] => 3
        [4] => 3
        [5] => 'E'
        [6] => 612
    )

 )
```

but i don't know why oputput, of this code, is this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1530270934000
        [1] => 19.4034
        [2] => -155.2675
        [3] => 3
        [4] => 1
        [5] => E
        [6] => 612
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1530270934000
        [1] => 19.4034
        [2] => -155.2675
        [3] => 3
        [4] => 2
        [5] => E
        [6] => 612
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1530270934000
        [1] => 19.4034
        [2] => -155.2675
        [3] => 3
        [4] => 3
        [5] => E
        [6] => 612
    )

 )
```

Comment: What type of value do you want to keep ? This is unclear

Comment: Have you checked your functions conditions to check which array index is "supposed" to be unset?

Comment: How is unclear ? i show even the outoput that i would to have...

Comment: showing desired input doesn't make things clear. Also this seems a really inefficient way of achieving your goal

Comment: array[1][0] is string (in the example) but should be integer, so this item (array[1]) should delete....

Comment: also with your set of `is_int || ...` you are basicly allowing everything.

Comment: You are sometimes better off saying `is_string()` to check rather than not `is_int()`

Answer (score 3):

Readable code is much easier to debug, for example:

```
function pulisci_array48mom(array $input): array {
    // filter the input,        by
    return array_filter($input, function ($entry) {

        // each index
        return is_int($entry[0])
            && is_double($entry[1])
            && is_double($entry[2])
            && is_numeric($entry[3])
            && is_numeric($entry[4])
            && is_string($entry[5])
            && is_int($entry[6]);
    });
}

$input = pulisci_array48mom([
    [1530270934000,   19.4034, -155.2675, 3, 1, 'E', 612],
    ['1530270934000', 19.4034, -155.2675, 3, 2, 'E', 612],
    [1530270934000,   19.4034, -155.2675, 3, 3, 'E', 612],
]);

print_r($input);
```

demo: https://3v4l.org/vccgY

Comment: any reference what is : array ?

Comment: @SanjayKumar That's a [`return type declaration`](http://php.net/manual/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't compare results of boolean functions to `true` or `false` you can simply use them directly.

If you need to check if a boolean function returns false add a NOT operator in front of it, a `!`

```
if( !is_int($var) )
```

reads as `if $var is not an integer`

Also, don't modify an array from it's initial loop. Store the indexes where you wish to modify and iterate those indexes. I added a `$todelete` array where I store the indexes of items to delete. Then I iterate that array and delete those indexes in the original array.

I also modified your if statement to be easier comprehensible.

All items will return false if they are what they are should be. If one doesn't match what is allowed it will return true, and satisfying the OR matches.

You could also do the inverse, remove the NOT operators `!` and replace the OR operators `||` with AND operators `&&`

See it online: https://ideone.com/oUHTKR

```
<?php
$array48mom = [ 
        [1530270934000, 19.4034, -155.2675, 3, 1, 'E', 612],
        ['1530270934000', 19.4034, -155.2675, 3, 2, 'E', 612],
        [1530270934000, 19.4034, -155.2675, 3, 3, 'E', 612]
    ];
$array48mom = pulisci_array48mom($array48mom);

function pulisci_array48mom(&$array48mom){
    $todelete = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array48mom); $i++) {    
        if(
               !is_int($array48mom[$i][0])
            || !is_double($array48mom[$i][1])
            || !is_double($array48mom[$i][2]) 
            || !is_numeric($array48mom[$i][3]) 
            || !is_numeric($array48mom[$i][4]) 
            || !is_string($array48mom[$i][5]) 
            || !is_int($array48mom[$i][6]) 
        ){
           $todelete[] = $i; 
        }
    }
    foreach($todelete as $key) {
       unset($array48mom[$key]);
    } 
    $array48mom = array_values($array48mom);    
    return $array48mom; 
}
print_r($array48mom);
```

What would even be better than rolling your own function is using [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) like highlighted in the [answer of Yoshi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51101584/1356107)

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine to expect this change || to &&

```
<?php 
$array48mom = pulisci_array48mom($array48mom);

function pulisci_array48mom(&$array48mom){
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array48mom); $i++) {    
        if( (
            (is_int($array48mom[$i][0]) == true) 
            && (is_double($array48mom[$i][1]) == true) 
            && (is_double($array48mom[$i][2])== true) 
            && (is_numeric($array48mom[$i][3]) == true) 
            && (is_numeric($array48mom[$i][4]) == true) 
            && (is_string($array48mom[$i][5]) == true) 
            && (is_int($array48mom[$i][6]) == true)) == false
        ){
            unset($array48mom[$i]); 
        }
    }
    $array48mom = array_values($array48mom);    
    return $array48mom; 
}
print_r($array48mom);
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Try this out buddy !!

```
<?php

    $array48mom = Array( 
        Array(1530270934000,19.4034,-155.2675,3,1,'E',612),
        Array('1530270934000',19.4034,-155.2675,3,2,'E',612),
        Array(1530270934000,19.4034,-155.2675,3,3,'E',612)
    );

    $array48mom = pulisci_array48mom($array48mom);

    function pulisci_array48mom(&$array48mom){
        for($i = 0; $i < count($array48mom); $i++) {    
            if( 
                (is_int($array48mom[$i][0]))!== true 
                || (is_double($array48mom[$i][1])) !== true
                || (is_double($array48mom[$i][2])) !== true
                || (is_numeric($array48mom[$i][3])) !== true
                || (is_numeric($array48mom[$i][4]))!== true 
                || (is_string($array48mom[$i][5])) !== true
                || (is_int($array48mom[$i][6]))!== true
            ){
                echo "UNSET {$i}\r\n";
                unset($array48mom[$i]); 
            }
        }
        $array48mom = array_values($array48mom);    
        return $array48mom; 
    }
    print_r($array48mom);
```